# Filtering file for command line tool

Tags: python, logging

I've written a little command-line utility for filtering log files. It's like grep, except instead of operating on lines it operates on log4j-style messages, which may span multiple lines, with the first line always including the logging level (TRACE, DEBUG etc.).

Example usage on a file short.log with contents like this:

> ```
> 16:16:12 DEBUG - Something happened, here's a couple lines of info:
>  debug line
>  another debug line
> 16:16:14 - I'm being very verbose 'cause you've put me on TRACE
>   trace info
> 16:16:15 TRACE - single line trace
> 16:16:16 DEBUG - single line debug
> ```

`logrep -f short.log DEBUG` produces:

> ```
> 16:16:12 DEBUG - Something happened, here's a couple lines of info:
>  debug line
>  another debug line
> 16:16:16 DEBUG - single line debug
> ```

I think the main loop of the program could probably be simplified with some sort of parse and filter.

```python
  file = fileinput.input(options.file)
  try:
    line = file.next()
    while True:
      if any(s in line for s in loglevels):
        if filter in line:
          sys.stdout.write(line)
          line = file.next()
          while not any(s in line for s in loglevels):
            sys.stdout.write(line)
            line = file.next()
          continue
      line = file.next()
  except StopIteration:
    return
```

Comment: Shouldn't you consider the log level only if it is at the beginning of the line? A line could contain info without being the first line of an info log. (Also you should log on a single line and use other separators if its spans on multiple "lines" but that is just my point of view because I handle huge quantities of logs)

Comment: The level isn't at the beginning of the line, it's after a timestamp. I could parse it to ensure the level is where I expect it to be, but I'm trying to be robust to minor changes in logging format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two problems with your loops.

In terms of style, calling `file.next()` and catching `StopIteration` is highly unconventional.  The normal way to iterate is:

```
for line in fileinput.input(options.file):
    …
```

In terms of functionality, I would personally consider the grepper to be buggy because it will fail to find a log message where the `filter` keyword that you are seeking appears on a continuation line.

To solve both problems, I would decompose the problem into two parts: reconstructing the logical messages (somewhat ugly) and searching (relatively straightforward).

```
import fileinput
import re

def log_messages(lines):
    """
    Given an iterator of log lines, generate pairs of
    (level, message), where message is a logical log message.
    possibly multi-line.
    """
    log_level_re = re.compile(r'\b(TRACE|DEBUG|WARN|ERROR|CRITICAL)\b')
    message = None
    for line in lines:
        match = log_level_re.search(line)
        if match:                               # First line
            if message is not None:
                yield level, message
            level, message = match.group(), line
        elif message is not None:               # Continuation line
            message += line
    if message is not None:                     # End of file
        yield level, message

for level, message in log_messages(fileinput.input(options.file)):
    if filter in message:
        sys.stdout.write(message)
```

Note that I've used a regular expression to look for TRACE, DEBUG, etc.  The `\b` anchors ensure that we don't mistake words like "INTRACELLULAR" for a TRACE message.